# Paragraph needs to have 2lines or 3lines of sentences not just one line

Tags: xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In my xml feed i have … … replace it with period. and space & also i need to <p> tag after every two or three senctences using xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417325/in-my-xml-feed-i-have-replace-it-with-period-and-space-also-i-need-to-p)

This is XML:

```
<data>The production of opium itself has basically not changed since
ancient times...Opium trade became more regular by the seventeenth
century, when it was mixed with tobacco for smoking, and addiction was
first recognized... This is a test Message3…This is showing off a
handful of updates to its line of audio accessories this week at IFA
in Berlin. At top of the list is the newly revealed inAir 5000, a
hefty tabletop AirPlay speaker that the company is firmly positioning
to take on Bowers&Wilkins' Zeppelin line (which also recently got its
own AirPlay version)... Like that system, the inAir certainly offers a
unique take on aesthetics, with a teardrop design. The company opted
not to install an Apple dock on the 110 watt system, given that
compatible devices can stream audio wirelessly to the thing via
AirPlay...Twice a month, tourists board a bus and embark on a "fact-finding mission" to one of the hottest spots in the immigration debate -- the Arizona-Mexico border. Tourists are encouraged to make make up their own minds..."Contagion" is an action-thriller about the pandemic outbreak of a deadly virus. It is part fantasy, part reality and totally possible, says one global health expert...The families are trying to raise the bail money.</data>
```

using xsl
Paragraph needs to split into three equal lines,but not just one like and one another thing is i need to remove '...', '…' and replace it with just period.

```
<p>This is showing off a handful of updates to its line of audio accessories this week at IFA in Berlin. At top of the list is the newly revealed inAir 5000, a hefty tabletop AirPlay speaker that the company is firmly positioning to take on Bowers&Wilkins' Zeppelin line (which also recently got its own AirPlay version).</p>
<p>Like that system, the inAir certainly offers a unique take on aesthetics, with a teardrop design. The company opted not to install an Apple dock on the 110 watt system, given that compatible devices can stream audio wirelessly to the thing via AirPlay.Twice a month, tourists board a bus and embark on a "fact-finding mission" to one of the hottest spots in the immigration debate -- the Arizona-Mexico border. Tourists are encouraged to make make up their own minds.</p>
```

"Contagion" is an action-thriller about the pandemic outbreak of a deadly virus. It is part fantasy, part reality and totally possible, says one global health expert.The families are trying to raise the bail money.

Comment: You only have two `p` tags in your desired results.

Comment: In my live xml feed i will have more than two p tags it is an example to express my problem.

Comment: In each p tag it should contain  3 sentences.

Comment: But in your example output the 1st paragraph contains 2 sentences and the seconf paragraph contains 4 sentences ?????

Comment: sorry for the confusion. <P> needs to have 3 sentence not just one sentence.

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope this answer is what you need:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="string-length(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstparagraph" select="substring(., 1, string-length(.)-($count*0.67))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="afterfirstparagraph" select="substring-after(., $firstparagraph)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="countafterfirstparagraph" select="string-length($afterfirstparagraph)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="secondparagraph" select="substring($afterfirstparagraph, 1, string-length($afterfirstparagraph)-($countafterfirstparagraph*0.5))"/>
    <xsl:element name="data">
      <xsl:element name="p">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(substring(., 1, string-length(.)-($count*0.67)), '\.\.\.', '.'), '…', '.')"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="p">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(substring($afterfirstparagraph, 1, string-length($afterfirstparagraph)-($countafterfirstparagraph*0.5)), '\.\.\.', '.'), '…', '.')"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="p">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(substring-after(., $secondparagraph), '\.\.\.', '.'), '…', '.')"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note that you have to replace "&" with its unicode.